# Flink and RocksDB - List State Larger Than Main Memory?

Tags: java, apache-flink, rocksdb

As I understand, RocksDB data is stored off-heap in RocksDB instances or on disk until the data is deserialized in a RocksDBState class in Flink. Is it possible to have a single list state that's larger than the current Java heap size/off heap size? From looking at the code in RocksDBListState.java, it seems that it tries to deserialize the entire list at once.

Comment: maybe if you increase the memory parameters at `flink-conf.yaml`: `jobmanager.heap.size` and `taskmanager.memory.process.size` as described here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/ops/config.html#basic-setup

Answer (score 0):

if you called ListState.add(Object in), it only deserializes the current input Object not all elements in the ListState

```
public void add(V value) {
    Preconditions.checkNotNull(value, "You cannot add null to a ListState.");

    try {
        this.writeCurrentKeyWithGroupAndNamespace();
        byte[] key = this.dataOutputView.getCopyOfBuffer();
        this.dataOutputView.clear();
        this.elementSerializer.serialize(value, this.dataOutputView);
        this.backend.db.merge(this.columnFamily, this.writeOptions, key, this.dataOutputView.getCopyOfBuffer());
    } catch (Exception var3) {
        throw new FlinkRuntimeException("Error while adding data to RocksDB", var3);
    }
}
```